# resume from network interuption in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, networking

Hi guys I am using Ubuntu 9.04. Things are cool, except for the annoying part about networking.
Say, if I am connected to a LAN cable, and somehow the connection is lost (let it be network congestion or my kicking the power cable), I will then be unable to get connected again.
I tried restarting the modem, unplugging and replugging it, clicking the network icon and telling it to connect, but the only thing that works is to restart the computer.
I know Karmic will be out in a few days but there's no warranty that the problem will be gone. So please tell me why and how to fix this, or at least some workaround (so that I don't have to restart the whole PC).
PS: everything is fine under Windows, which means it's not a hardware fault.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run "tail -f /var/log/messages" before replugging your network cable.  What messages appear?  What if you run "sudo ifconfig eth0 down ;sudo ifconfig eth0 up"? Again, what messages appear in /var/log/messages?  What if you run "sudo dhclient eth0"?

Comment: great, thanks
"sudo ifconfig eth0 down ;sudo ifconfig eth0 up" fixed the problem

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
service network restart
```

in the terminal.

Comment: you mean `service networking restart`?
it says "OK", but doesn't connect :(